# Error setting up base reposotory while using pxe booting centos9 with kickstart file

Tags: networking, centos7, pxe-boot, tftp, centos9

I am trying to setup a PXE boot server in centos for unattended install of OS, for POC I am using a centos7 as a PXE server which is running on Citrix hypervisor, I am using a kickstart file. When I try to boot a machine on network boot it is taking all the Parameters from kickstart file(eg, keyboard ,language ,time) however it is giving "Error setting up base repository" on installation source section. How can I solve this issue. I saw a few articles but could not understand what I am doing wrong
Note: I am trying to install centos 9.

the ks file:

```
#version=DEVEL
# System authorization information
auth --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512
# Use CDROM installation media
#using network boot
url --url="http://192.168.10.9/centos9"
# Use graphical install
graphical
# Run the Setup Agent on first boot
firstboot --enable
ignoredisk --only-use=xvda
# Keyboard layouts
keyboard --vckeymap=us --xlayouts='us'
# System language
lang en_US.UTF-8

# Network information
network  --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0 --onboot=off --ipv6=auto --no-activate
network  --hostname=localhost.localdomain

# Root password
rootpw --iscrypted $6$KWLJKbrttDYtjWnk$rjRC4pR6ntyzYtJ7xjqOGC/0FYnlNEc6nacNP3Av93msT0aTLy10SUcKNaMvtkYN6gW2z128oB5aCMAhIlgXH0
# System services
services --disabled="chronyd"
# System timezone
timezone Asia/Kolkata --isUtc --nontp
# System bootloader configuration
bootloader --append=" crashkernel=auto" --location=mbr --boot-drive=xvda
autopart --type=lvm
# Partition clearing information
clearpart --none --initlabel

%packages
@^minimal
@core
kexec-tools

%end

%addon com_redhat_kdump --enable --reserve-mb='auto'

%end

%anaconda
pwpolicy root --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --notempty
pwpolicy user --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --emptyok
pwpolicy luks --minlen=6 --minquality=1 --notstrict --nochanges --notempty
%end
```

Comment: We can only guess without showing the Kickstart file.

Comment: The kickstart file was taken from the centos7 installation (anacondaks.cfg) , and and commented the cdrom installation and added the URL for the KS file url --url="http://192.168.10.9/centos9/ks.cfg", I will attach the KS file as I don't have access to server today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out the solution, don't know if it is the standard way.

added the below line in my kickstart file

```
repo --name="BaseOS" --baseurl="http://192.168.10.9/centos9/BaseOS"
```

(here the IP is the IP of my PXE server and centos9 is the folder where all the installation files are, and BaseOS is folder has the repositories)

however just adding the above line didn't solved the issue as BaseOS is not the only repository which it required , it required AppStream as well however simply adding

```
repo --name="AppStream" --baseurl="http://192.168.10.9/centos9/AppStream"
```

didn't seem to work so I copied all the content of the Appstream folder to the folder where all OS files were there ie, centos9.

adding my ks file for reference:

```
lang en_US
keyboard --xlayouts='us'
timezone Asia/Kolkata --utc
rootpw $2b$10$l1loZtoAcesh8JpVrm5/ReXAyhLwvljGp1VRBagrylJd16O2uDh66 --iscrypted
repo --name="BaseOS" --baseurl="http://192.168.10.9/centos9/BaseOS"
reboot
url --url=http://192.168.10.9/centos9
bootloader --append="rhgb quiet crashkernel=1G-4G:192M,4G-64G:256M,64G-:512M"
zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel
autopart
network --bootproto=dhcp
firstboot --disable
selinux --disabled
firewall --enabled --http
%packages
@^graphical-server-environment
%end
```

Comment: Happy to hear it's resolved. FWIW, I don't think it should have been necessary to combine your AppStream repository into BaseOS. It's possible that the AppStream URL wasn't exposed via the web server, or there was another issue with the repository metadata that made it unusable at that location. (`./repodata`)

Comment: The appstream URL was actually exposed through webserver, as when I manually added the path for the appstream folder  it started working, It should be the issue with the metadata, not sure as I am a begineer.